# Trying to remove punctuations from a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the function I'm using to remove punctuations from a column in `pandas`.

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)
```

This is how I'm applying it.

```
review_without_punctuation = products['review'].apply(remove_punctuation)
```

Here products is the `pandas` dataframe.

This is the error message that I get.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-196c188dfb67> in <module>()
----> 1 review_without_punctuation = products['review'].apply(remove_punctuation)

/Users/username/Dropbox/workspace/private/pydev/ml/classification/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2292             else:
   2293                 values = self.asobject
-> 2294                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2295 
   2296         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:66124)()

<ipython-input-18-0950dc65d8b8> in remove_punctuation(text)
      1 def remove_punctuation(text):
----> 2     return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Give us a small example DataFrame please.

Comment: Can you check if there is any 'nan' or non-string value in any row of the column `review`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to avoid running pure Python code via `apply()` in Pandas.  It's slow.  Instead, use the special [`str` property](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) which exists on every [Pandas string series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
In [9]: s = pd.Series(['hello', 'a,b,c', 'hmm...'])
In [10]: s.str.replace(r'[^\w\s]', '')
Out[10]: 
0    hello
1      abc
2      hmm
dtype: object
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your `avoid running pure Python code via apply() in Pandas`??? I always thought it is the right way as it's fastest because it's vectorized and most straightforward.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov: To me, "vectorized" means "There is no loop executing Python code on each row individually."  All `apply()` does is run Python code on each row individually.  And it's slow.  It's just a pretty way of doing something you should not do.  If you pass a `ufunc` (a special kind of function which is not a regular Python function) to `apply()`, then it is truly "vectorized" (i.e. fast).

Comment: Can you tell what is the part `r'[^\w\s]'` doing or what this regex there for?

Comment: @KPMG: `\w` means words and `\s` means spaces.  The `[^` in front of them means "anything other than these."  So we are replacing anything other than words and spaces with the empty string, i.e. we are removing punctuation and other unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your `apply` is applied wrongly.

The correct way to do it is:

```
import re
s = pd.Series(['hello', 'a,b,c', 'hmm...'])
s.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',x))
0    hello
1      abc
2      hmm
dtype: object
```

(hat tip to @John Zwinck for `regex`)

Comparing this to another solution:

```
%timeit s.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',x))
%timeit s.str.replace(r'[^\w\s]', '')
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 310 µs per loop
```

Comment: The `str.replace()` method is faster than `apply()` when the series is long.  But not by too much, because the function being applied is trivial.